# gulp-useref don't build my remote hosted files into min.js

Tags: gulp, gulp-useref

Hi I try to build all css and js into /dist/ but I only have the local file... why useref don't download ands put my jquery cdn from google into ma min.js

please there is solution for this (I don't really want to use an package manager as bower) I prefer gulp-useref do this work... idea?

Answer (score 1):

It only works on relative url's, not absolute url's. It does not have the ability to download remote files and compile them, and that's always risky anyway. You should import these assets from a package manager and compile them that way. That's the only way that `gulp-useref` currently supports.